# add php array element to an array how has same key and value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this how had same gtin:

```
Array
(
    [0]
        (
            [status] => ERROR
            [message] => 'message error'
            [gtin] => 03661733003170
        )

    [1]
        (
            [status] => SUCCESS
            [message] => 
            [gtin] => 03661985096630
        )
)
```

and another array like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [e_id] => 219
            [v_id] => 20
            [gtin] => 03661733003170
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [e_id] => 217
            [v_id] => 15
            [gtin] => 03661985096630
        )


)
```

I want to combine this two array in one array how has the same gtin like this I have try lot of php function but nothing resold my problem:

```
Array
(
    [03661733003170]
        (
            [status] => ERROR
            [message] => 'message error'
            [e_id] => 219,
            [v_id] => 20
        )

    [03661985096630]
        (
            [status] => SUCCESS
            [message] => 
            [evt_id] => 217,
            [evl_id] => 15
        )
)
```

thank for help

Comment: please show what you tried and what went wrong. Then at least we have got somewhere to start from.

Comment: This is not even valid php syntax

Comment: @AmeliaMagee No but it looks like the output of a `print_r` command, so it's entirely understandable that it looks like that. This is data rather than code, after all, so it doesn't really need to be valid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all keys are numeric and iteritable and that both arrays are of equal length, a simple loop with [array_merge()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) is probably your best bet.

```
$myarray1 = ....
$myarray2 = ....
$resultarray = array();

for ($i = 0; $i == sizeof($myarray1); $i++) {
    $resultarray[$i] = array_merge($myarray1[$i], $myarray2[$i]);
}
```